# rsyslog not catching output?

Tags: linux, command-line

I can push [stdout](/questions/tagged/stdout) **/** [stderr](/questions/tagged/stderr) from the [ping](/questions/tagged/ping) command to rsyslog like so:

```
ping www.superuser.com 2>&1 | logger -p user.info
```

On my system, the "live" output can be watched with a simple `tail -f /var/log/messages` . It goes there because of the corresponding line in my `/etc/rsyslog.config` :

```
# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                -/var/log/messages
```

However, the same thing does not work for my custom program:

```
myprogram 2>&1 | logger -p user.info
```

The myprogram binary does not return/exit immediately after call - it will run for some time - and every now and then print messages (using printf) to the console. It behaves this way if I do not pipe its output into logger. Correct me if I am wrong, but this behavior is similar to the [ping](/questions/tagged/ping) command (at least when the destination is reached).

Why then am I not seeing the output of myprogram in `/var/log/messages` ? Could the output be buffered somehow and it simply is not getting to logger yet? Could it be something else about the `rsyslog.conf` configuration line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the output from `myprogram` being buffered. Using tricks mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332045/bash-force-execd-process-to-have-unbuffered-stdout) I came up with a quick solution:

```
script -q -c "myprogram" | logger -p user.info
```